# Number fields with only totally positive or totally negative units

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $L$ be a totally real Galois extension, that is cyclic and of odd prime degree $p>2$. Let $\mathcal{O}_L$ be the ring of integers of $L$, and let $U=\mathcal{O}_L^\times$ be the unit group. The only roots of unity in such an extension are $\pm 1$, thus by Dirichlet's unit theorem, 
$$\mathcal{O}_L^\times \cong \langle -1 , u_1, u_2, u_3, \ldots, u_{p-1} \rangle$$
for some units $u_1,\ldots,u_{p-1}$ of infinite order.

**Questions:**

- Is it possible for all $u_1,\ldots, u_{p-1}$ to be totally positive units? (A unit $u$ is totally positive if all its embeddings $\tau(u)\in \mathbb{R}$ are positive.)
- If so, how often would one expect this to happen?
- If it may occur, how would one detect this phenomenon without having to compute the entire unit group?

If $u$ is totally positive, then $-u$ is totally negative, so the question is asking whether there are such cyclic extensions $L/\mathbb{Q}$ with all units being totally positive or totally negative.

Comment: This can happen for $p=2$, so I don't see a reason *a priori* that this shouldn't happen for $p>2$. I estimate that if the signs of the embeddings of each unit are uniformly distributed (fix the first embedding to be positive), all generators should be totally positive with probability $(1/16)^4$?

Comment: Four fundamental units?  Not $p-1$?

Comment: This will happen if and only if $H^{\mathrm{nar}}/H$ has degree $2^{p-1}$, where $H$ is the Hilbert class field of $L$ and $H^{\mathrm{nar}}$ is the narrow Hilbert class field.  Don't know if that helps answer any of your questions though.

Comment: Oops, I had the case $p=5$ in mind, but the question is indeed about any $p>2$. Thanks for catching that. Could you elaborate on your answer in terms of the narrow Hilbert class field?

Comment: There is an exact sequence $1 \rightarrow E/E^{\mathrm{tp}} \rightarrow \oplus_{v \in \mathrm{Pl}_{\infty}^{r}} \{ \, \pm 1 \, \} \rightarrow \mathrm{Gal}(H^{\mathrm{nar}}/H) \rightarrow 1$. Here, $E^{\mathrm{tp}}$ is the group of totally positive units in $L$, the direct sum is over the real places of $L$, and the last arrow is the global reciprocity map from the idelic formulation of class field theory. See, for instance, Chapter III Theorem 1.1 of Gras "Class Field Theory" and also the remark 1.1.5 following it.

Comment: THANK YOU! This is very helpful.

Comment: Or, the "ray class" formulation may be conceptually simpler.  The group $\mathrm{Gal} (H^{\mathrm{nar}}/H)$ is isomorphic to the principal ideals of $L$ modulo the principal ideals with totally positive generator.  If all units are totally positive, then the signature of the generator of a principal ideal is not affected by switching to a different generator (i.e., multiplying by a unit).  So we get an injection from this quotient to $\oplus_{v \in \mathrm{Pl}_{\infty}^r} \{ \, \pm 1 \, \}$ sending a generator to its signature.  Any signature is possible, so it's also a surjection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A list of references concerning what has been done on this question may be found [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.5674.pdf); the question on how often this happens is being studied in [this artcle](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.00092.pdf). I guess you may assume that any questions not answered in these papers are open problems.